# Trying to integrate WWise into a C++ project. Can't play any sound

Tags: c++, wwise

I'm currently attempting to integrate WWise into my project. I can't seem to get the audio to play.

In WWise, i created a simple event that plays a sound (Lets call the event "Terrain_Gravel_SFX")

In the project, I started with calling the initialization functions such as :

```
AK::MemoryMgr::Init

AK::StreamMgr::Init

AK::SoundEngine::Init

AK::MusicEngine::init

AK::SpatialAudio::Init
```

After all the initialization calls return AK_Success, I began loading the required banks (Init.bnk + Test.bnk), which also return AK_Success. I'm also calling AK::SoundEngine::RenderAudio() every frame, as instructed by the sample project.

After posting the event ( AK::SoundEngine::PostEvent(AK::EVENTS::TERRAIN_GRAVEL_SFX) ), the sfx doesn't play. Are there any functions I should be calling? Attempting to use the Soundbanks included in the IntegrationDemo also plays nothing.

Edit : Looking at the output window, its shows AK error : voice starvation at the end of the frame when I call PostEvent

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, turn out I needed to set a gameObject as the default listener by calling

```
AK::SoundEngine::SetDefaultListener(gameObject_ID, listener_count)
```